# Character dropped in BIND expression

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have run into an interesting situation while upgrading some legacy code from CF10 to CF2018. A query is segmented in string pieces in a webpage and passed through a CFGRID BIND statement to a query in a .cfc file.

The .CFC handles several webpages for the CFGRID.  The various webpages provide input fields for filtering the data in the grid, such as searches, dates, etc.

Several of the queries use the JOIN (+) shortcut notation in the WHERE statement.

My problem is that somewhere between the CFGRID and the .CFC, the "+" is getting dropped and replaced with a space.

DisplayHistoryReceived.cfm

```
Conditions = "t.CPNId = pn.CPNId(+) 
    AND t.PartId = p.PartId 
    AND t.POId = po.POId(+) 
    AND t.LocationId = l.LocationId 
    AND l.BuildingId = b.BuildingId 
    AND t.StatusCodeId = sc.StatusCodeId(+) 
    AND t.TransTypesId = 1 
    AND po.OwnerId = o.OwnerId"
```

DisplayGrid-HTML.cfm

```
<CFGRID
    BIND="cfc:#application.area#.Components.Global.DrillDown.SearchGrid({dSource},{queryFieldNames},
{tableNames},{Conditions},{SearchField@change},SearchInput@keyup},{BooleanSelect@change},{BoolField},
{DFilters},DFilterLine1},{DFilterLine2},{DFilterLine3},{DateRange},{DateAfter},{DateBefore},{OrderBy},
{GroupBy},{pSize},{cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection},{cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize})"
```

DrillDown.cfc

```
<CFQUERY NAME="grd" DATASOURCE="#dSource#">
    SELECT DISTINCT #Fields#
    FROM #PreserveSingleQuotes(Tables)#
    WHERE #PreserveSingleQuotes(Conditions)#
    <!--- Used to filter based on a TEXT search --->
    <cfif '#sInput#' neq ''>
        AND #sField# like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#sInput#%"/>
    </cfif>
```

[more CFIF statements follow]

The error message that I get is: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00904: "SC"."STATUSCODEID": invalid identifier

But this excerpt from the error message leads me to think that something may have happened in CF2018 instead:

```
WHERE t.CPNId = pn.CPNId( ) 
    AND t.PartId = p.PartId 
    AND t.POId = po.POId( ) 
    AND t.LocationId = l.LocationId 
    AND l.BuildingId = b.BuildingId 
    AND t.StatusCodeId = sc.StatusCodeId( ) 
    AND t.TransTypesId = 1 
    AND po.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
```

Any ideas, besides rewriting all the queries with standard JOINS?  There are several pages scattered throughout the site that use this.

Comment: You might get some joy by using an older oracle driver, but that might cause other problems.  Plus, the fact that it happened on the 3rd plus sign and not the first might be relevent.

Comment: It is strange, but I have noticed that errors in SQL seem to be reported from the bottom up.  That even happens in SQL Developer.  However I still think that ColdFusion is parsing the string somewhere between the BIND and the CFQUERY.  Here is an excerpt from a <CFLog> that is inserted  after the <CFArgument> tags in the function.  
"Conditions: t.CPNId = pn.CPNId( ) AND t.PartId = p.PartId  AND t.POId = po.POId( ) AND t.LocationId = l.LocationId  AND l.BuildingId = b.BuildingId AND t.StatusCodeId = sc.StatusCodeId( ) AND t.TransTypesId = 1 AND po.OwnerId = o.OwnerId"

Comment: Update: Never use raw sql/commands from the client side, or PreserveSingleQuotes for that matter. Aside from issues like this, both put your database at risk by making it vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should rewrite the code/queries to only pass simple parameters and build any conditional statements on the server side. Make sure to wrap all literals in cfqueryparam and avoid executing raw commands from the client side.